# R: How to store matrix element value as numeric/integer

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have this line of code:

```
value4=sign(t(x)[1,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))
```

when I run it the result will be a 1x1 matrix:

```
     [,1]
[1,]   -1
```

I want to store this value(-1) as numeric, is there any R function with which I can do that?

Comment: Found it, it is `as.numeric(value4)`

Comment: or just coerce with `c(value4)`